# How to input actual data into classes

Tags: python, class

Okay, so I have a module I created and have imported it into my main program. I guess I'm still trying to understand classes and I'm not sure how to actually enter my data into my class. This is in Python 3. Here is the module:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, Title = '', Ratings = []):
        self.Movie = Title
        self.Ratings = Ratings
        self.TotalRatings = 0
        self.minusFive = 0
        self.minusThree = 0 
        self.one = 0
        self.three = 0
        self.five = 0
        self.ValidRatings = [-5,-3,1,3,5]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} has {1} total ratings with an average rating of {3}.'.format(self.title, self.totalRatings, self.AvgRating)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
    def AddRating(self, rating):
        for num in self.Ratings:
            if num in self.ValidRatings:
                self.totalRatings += 1 
            else:
                continue
    def AvgRating(self):
        return sum (self.totalRatings)/len(self.totalRatings)
```

Below is the beginning of my main program:

```
import Movie

def ReadFile(FileName):
    F = open(FileName)
    return F.readlines()

File = ReadFile('Ratings.txt') 
File2 = open('Prog5Titles.txt').read()       #open movie titles file

movie1 = Movie("The Avengers", [5,5,5])     #this is just a sample to help me understand
```

When I run this, I am getting the error message: 'module' object is not callable. Can anyone help me understand how to correctly input my data into this?

Comment: Aside: the line `def __init__(self, Title = '', Ratings = []):` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  Instead of making a new empty `Ratings` list every time `__init__` is called without one being passed, it makes exactly *one*, when the function is defined.  Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) on how mutable default arguments work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have a file Movie.py that contains a class named, by coincidence, Movie.  If you just `import Movie`, then the python name Movie refers to *the contents of the file Movie.py* and to refer to the class tucked away in there, you need to write:

```
 movie1 = Movie.Movie("The Avengers", [5,5,5])
```

Alternatively, you can do your import like this:

```
from Movie import Movie
```

and now the python name Movie refers to something different — the "thing" (in this case, a class) named Movie inside the file Movie.py.

This would be a little clearer if you named the file containing `class Movie` with a name *different* from the class defined inside the file.  Maybe `movie_stuff.py` or something.  Consider that you'll have additional classes in the project (Actor, Studio) and those classes will probably be defined in the same file as class Movie.

Comment: Okay, well I got that all figured out, but now I still am not sure how to go about the problem. Here is a link to my new question if anyone wants to visit it and help me out...